# What is the perimeter and area for this simple shape?

Tags: geometry

[image]

What is the perimeter and area of the shape in the picture?

Comment: Can you express this shape as a difference of two other shapes? Do you know the formulas for the areas and perimeters of those shapes?

Comment: Find the area of the entire rectangle then subtract it by the area of the semicircle, see if that helps.

Comment: Where are you stuck ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a diagram to help visualize the problem better. Notice that I've added a red line.
[image]
There is a semicircle and the full rectangle. Thus, you should use:
$$A=A_{\text{rectangle}}-A_{\text{semicircle}}$$
Where $A$ is the area of the full shape. Can you evaluate the radius of the semicircle $r$?

From the value of $r$, can you find the area of this semicircle?

---

Now, for the perimeter. One may write:
$$P=9+6+9+1+1+P_{\text{semi circle}}$$
Can you find the perimeter of the semicircle from the value of $r$ you calculated previously?

Comment: The area would be 47.72 cm²
and the perimeter would be 32.28 cm
am I correct?

Comment: @Alfarissaoud Yes, indeed you are right. I double checked. Note that the answers you gave are obviously approximate.

Comment: Thanks! the problem was that the answers in the book followed the previous edition, so they were wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The area of the rectangle, with side lengths $6$ and $9$ is $6*9 = 54$. We now want to take that little cut out of it and subtract the area of the rectangle by it. To do this, we need to find that shape's area as well. We can recognize that it is a semicircle, which has area ${\pi}r^2\over2$ where the diameter is 4 so the radius must be 2. So our final answer is :

$54 - 2{\pi}$

As for perimeter, the perimeter of a rectangle is the sum of all of it's side lengths so we add all of them together $9+6+9+2+$ perimeter of the semicircle and the perimeter of the semicircle is normally ${\pi d\over2}+d$ but in our case we just want the first part so we end up with $26+{\pi d\over2}$ = $26+2\pi$

Comment: what about the perimeter? that is part of the question

Comment: You only cover area, not perimeter.

Comment: @Cursed1701 didn't notice it till just now, I'll do that next.

Comment: @Cursed1701 Note that the semicircle has a diameter of 6 - (1 + 1).

Comment: @ClassicEndingMusic i know the answer here, and am reccomending closure due to a homework style question with lack of evidence of attempt to solve, this is me trying to get someone who has treid to answer, to answer in full

Comment: Why is it (54−2²π) only half a circle occupies that space not a full circle,
so it should be (54-0.5x2²xπ)?

Comment: Mighta accidentally deleted this, also @Alfarissaoud it is because the area of a semicircle is ${{\pi}r^2\over2}$